Can we understand the meaning of moral statements by what in the mind causes them to be made?
When a person says "this is morally good" or "this is morally bad," something caused them to make this statement. Typical causes may include:

They were told by their parents that it's good/bad
They were told in church that God likes/doesn't like it
They believe a group would function better if it was done
They like/don't like when it's done to them
It makes them feel bad when it's done to others
They are aware of a consensus among other people that it's good/bad (like a Keynesian beauty contest).
They believe it would lead to consequences that they consider good/bad for one of these reasons.

Can the meaning of their claim be understood solely in terms of what caused them to utter it?
So for example, if someone thinks other people would say something is bad, and as a result they say it is bad, the true meaning if we dissect their claim is just that "other people would say this is bad," with nothing beyond that. Or if someone thinks God doesn't like something, and as a result they say it is bad, the true meaning of this claim is "God doesn't like it." And that these are therefore different claims; one person is really just saying "other people don't like this," and the other person is really just saying "God doesn't like this," and to use the term "morally bad" for both is a form of equivocation.
This is not to say all possible causes are part of the meaning; only to say that the meaning can be found somewhere within the causes.
Or - the alternative - can there be some "hidden meaning" of moral goodness/badness that goes beyond, that even the person uttering the claim is not aware of and that did not cause them to utter it?

Yes. You are asking about making a formal model of how people form moral judgments. You are also asking about discovering correlations which hint at unidentified factors, perhaps using techniques related to factor analysis, which I bet have category-theoretic analogues, which make their core properties clearer.
I am spending my time studying how to build formal models and formal ontologies. I think that it’s possible that no one has created the model you describe yet, so perhaps you should try to. But as to the question “How could one?”, you would first have to choose a particular framework for representing this ontology. Some of the ones I know of are RDF, OWL, ologs (as well as relational ologs), algebraic property graphs, entity-relationship diagrams, description logic, relational algebra, SQL, Datalog, and my personal plug, categorial query language (CQL). This field is generally known as knowledge representation.
The question is complicated and has many sub-aspects. One not only must consider the exact characteristics of each concept in the ontology, but even the expressive properties of the underlying formal system you choose to define it in - first order logic, set theory, various types of type theory, etc. I was recently exposed to the data science expression “All models are bad but some models are useful”, meaning there maybe can never be a perfect model that canonically represents something in the world, so you have to make design choices and sacrifices depending on what aspect you want to highlight. I am not sure I agree with the spirit of this expression, though, and am interested in how category theory allows us to express concepts in terms of their “universal properties”.
A good tool to practice making ontologies is Protege.
Having been practicing making formal models, I have gotten better at drafting one by learning how certain concepts get mapped to certain mathematical structures (and I still have a lot to learn about that).

This could be some considerations to start you off:
You can usually begin by listing some of the fundamental ‘things’ at work in your ontology, but they could be abstract concepts or properties just as well as physical objects. It sounds like you have concepts like people, beliefs, moral beliefs, moral judgments, events, emotions, social relationships like friendships and communities, God, perception, and relational concepts like consensus. You can try to build basic relationships by writing out simple subject verb object or subject predicate sentences, like:

A person has a set of beliefs.
A belief is a proposition.
A moral belief is a proposition including a good/bad predicate.
A person’s moral beliefs are a function of their emotional reaction to perceiving an event; their belief about the beliefs of other people; the assertions about what’s good/bad they’ve encountered (from a certain class of people who have influence, like parents, teachers, etc.); and their beliefs about good/bad consequences of some action.

I have been mainly working with first order logic, set theory and category theory up until now, but am now branching out into type theory. How I would do it in set theory is:

a type of entity is a particular set. For example, a person is an element in the set of all people. (And having spent time thinking about this, I’ve come to believe that one should not worry at this stage about defining “the set of all people”; just assume it as a particular set (a constant in your signature). In reality, maybe it’s some arbitrary set in ZFC where each element “represents” a particular person; we don’t need to worry about specifically which set is being used for that purpose.)
Relationships between things are generally relations or functions. Collections of things are obviously sets - but if you are taking combinations of elements in a set, then that could be an element in the power set. So for example, each person has a set of beliefs; a belief is a proposition describing “the world”. So maybe we need to claim there is a language all the people use (which is clearly an oversimplifying assumption for now to make the modeling easier, which we can change later) to describe the world (some formal language we can define using first order logic). Then for the set of all well formed formulae, we take the power set - P(WFF(L)) - this is the set of all collections of beliefs. And we can assign each person to one of those sets. Clearly, this is a function: a person only gets one set of beliefs, but two people could happen to both be assigned the same set of beliefs. I only recently found it’s helpful to name functions with a predicate including both a verb and an object - like “hasAsBeliefs”. This defied intuition for me initially, since I thought it could either be just a verb, like “has”, or just a relationship label, like “beliefs”; but for certain reasons I currently see the above as a good choice. So we have hasAsBeliefs : People -> P(WFF(Language)).

And so on. It’s a long and complicated process building a good ontology, but category theory helps so much because it means there is a more dynamic,  computational relationship between the relations, which can be composed, and which allow us to define equality between difference compositions - for example, “mother of mother” = “grandmother”, so if we have a function “mother : People -> People”, and a function “grandmother : People -> P(People)” (because a person has a set of two people who are their grandmothers), then we can increase the functional “coherence” of the model by making a requirement: for any person, the mother of their mother must be a person in their set of grandmothers. This is known as data integrity.
This is a huge topic with so much to learn. I hope you pursue building such a model. Feel free to reach out at juliushamilton100@gmail.com if you want to collaborate on an ontology, I’m always looking to practice, since many big theoretical questions come up along the way as you consider the tiniest nuanced details; but the more you work through each one, the more habit you accumulate, making it easier and faster to make an ontology next time.

You say — [my emphasis added for discussion]

So for example, if someone thinks other people would say something is bad, and as a result they say it is bad, the true meaning if we dissect their claim is just that "other people would say this is bad," with nothing beyond that. Or if someone thinks God doesn't like something, and as a result they say it is bad, the true meaning of this claim is "God doesn't like it." And that these are therefore different claims; one person is really just saying "other people don't like this," and the other person is really just saying "God doesn't like this," and to use the term "morally bad" for both is a form of equivocation.

With due respect, I think this is backwards.
Lets start from the very beginning — when we were born.
 Yeah I admit I dont exactly remember 
 If someone has a better memory they can fill in and correct my conjectures

The earliest experiences of a human — as seen in 2nd person in the smiles/gurgles and the cries/bawls of babies — is “I like” and “I dislike”.
We may assume it's as basic as “I like Mama feeding me”;
“I dislike the feeling of hunger and/or having dirtied myself”
Everything starts here
Over time restrictions and taboos get learned  — the adults may think they are correcting/educating the child but for the most part it’s an elaborate programming process where some things are taught/learnt as good (to express) and conversely not good to express.
I suspect somewhere between 5 and 12 children learn that: “I hate XYZ” usually doesn't have the desired effect of Mama feeding/cleaning me. So we learn to lie.  “XYZ is bad” as an intended obscuration of  “I hate XYZ” is an important step in this education — so-called! — but what is really learned lying.
An important facet of growing up and education is learning the technique of presenting subjective emotions as objective facts. For this “good” and “bad” are primary building blocks.
Over time however others see through this lie. So more sophistication is learned. Much of moral judgmentality is just the reification of this process of effective falsifying.
Just as the hapless young 'un is learning to navigate and battle the crazy adult world, an enormous new explosion — the dangling apple of bliss occurs — puberty. The poor teenager experiences the promise here of indescribable happiness. Yet the very first forays in this direction are fraught — rebuffs if one is lucky, violence and worse at other times.
Every religious teaching of every time and clime would be found to agree on this — sexuality is a minefield of problems.  And sexuality is just a new arena of sensations.
Much of conventional morality is towards bringing some modicum of sense here — niddah laws of Judaism, purdah in Islam and of course the marriage/sexuality norms and prohibitions found in all cultures.
Anyone who sees all this clearly could not be pleased with the human condition
A notable philosopher of reversing this lying-habit was Korzybski — Whatever you say it is it isn't.
And after Korzybski the E-Prime movement where people take pains to avoid "to be" in all its forms in their speech.
In short

Much of the modern worldview (and modernity disorders) follow from Descartes’ sharp category separation of mind and body — the host in the machine weltanschauung.
Notable recent philosophical correctives for this error are Merleau-Ponty and George Lakoff.
(Spinoza was an early rebutter of cartesian dualism. Unfortunately, western thought chose to canonize Descartes and marginalize Spinoza).
From this pov, emotions are the junction of thoughts and the body.
And morality is the reification of the concealing of primal emotions — like, dislike

So...
To answer your question
The usual framing of questions of morality runs thus:

The world pre exists
In this world morality somehow exists objectively
In this objective world with objective morality I find myself existing...
... and somehow mysteriously apprehending said objective morality

Here is an alternate frame which, (IMHO) is more apposite for addressing questions of morality:

I (my subjectivity) exist
The earliest datum of my subjective existence is likes-dislikes
As I grow, I learn to connect "I like" to "I get"; "I dislike" to "I avoid" while simultaneously concealing this process
Morality is the expression of that in a socially acceptabilized manner


You could say that when you are born, other humans pre-exist, and they have subjective morality, so morality is objective for you. Then somehow we're not smart enough to realize that's what happened and we think that morality is objective totally. "If you had asked people what they wanted, they would have said 'smarter people'."

I don't understand @ScottRowe. Experientially (I guess the philosophy fancy word is "phenomenologically") we start by experiencing Mama — pleasant — in a harsh alien world. ("mama" and "mammal" are not coincidental small Hamming distance apart ) "Others" "World" etc are  much later concepts. A cursory glance even with our adult lying propensities baked on, would show there is no single unitary The World But everyone inhabits their own. That is in fact a defining characteristic of maya

Perhaps most people don't take a cursory glance, or they keep forgetting what they saw when they did? "None are so blind as those who will not see."

Short Answer
What you propose is to use speculative inference about the "real" motivations for our views, combined with a partial reduction to more base psychological motivations to mislead ourselves, as a way to rationalize not treating morality as real.  Well, Quine-Duhem makes clear that one can find rationales to defend basically any kind of theory, if one makes the theory and justifications sufficiently complicated.  So per Quine Duhem, the answer has to be a "yes".
Longer Answer
While the more base, misleading, or negative psychological motivations are demonstrably real, and present within each of our minds, this is true of basically all thoughts and inferences we have to reality.  We humans have found that inference to objective morality is far more useful than trying to explain morality away.  Inference to reality based on utility, is how indirect realism works.  It does not provide certainty, so dismissive attempts to reject candidate aspects of reality are not absurd, or obviously wrong without inspection.  But to date, the utility of treating morality as real far exceeds the utility of dismissing it.
Moral realism can be arrived at in two different forms.  One is to treat it as an aspect of the world that precedes humans. Another is to treat it as an intrinsic aspect of BEING human, or of being alive, as an emergent "social reality".  If abstract object realism is mentally difficult for someone to accept, then social emergence is an alternative useful framing.
I consider science to require the pre-acceptance of abstract object realism.  Math and logic are so central to science, and in particular to physics, that a large number of physicalists today have accepted them as part of physics, and thus as part of physicalism.  As morality is just a different form of abstract object, once one accepts math and logic as part of reality, I don't see the hurdle of values as a big additional deal, but that is me, and I am not a physicalist anyway.

I'm not sure how this addresses the question. Are you saying that people have other causes (besides those I listed) for believing moral claims, and that these other causes support a more universal notion of morality? (If so, what are those other causes and what makes them more universal?) Or are you saying that people have only the kinds of causes I listed for believing moral claims, and that nonetheless this supports a more universal notion of morality somehow? (if so, how?)

@causative -- We infer reality based on observations, and the utility of predictive models.  What you propose is similar to the behaviorist programme of reducing our mental modeling of other's minds to our observations of external behavior.  That leaves out so much predictive power from theory of mind, that it was a drastically dead end.  You at least are accepting theory of mind here, but reducing moral inference to our internal mind states, experiences, and motives, once more leaves out the complexity and predictive power of Popperian hypotheses of "conjectures and refutations".

Are you proposing there are useful "conjectures and refutations" in the field of moral inference, other than our internal mind states, experiences, and motives? What might those conjectures be? Are you talking about souls?

@Causitive -- the presumption of moral realism is that there is an abstract reality to morality, and that the human moral sense detects this reality and gives us access to this reality.   Models of how that might work are the "conjectures".  The alternative I noted was that morality might be an emergent social reality, which humans are evolved to detect.  Conjectures would spell out how that works too.   Dualism can be a fundamental assumption that informs these conjectures, but so can physicalism, idealism, etc.
